# .NET 8 serialization/deserialization of IEnumerable interface

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, serialization, system.text.json

Having following classes:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace SerializeCustomEnumerable;

public class Statistics<T> : IEnumerable<(int Year, T Value)> where T : new()
{
        // Underlying structure where data are stored 
        protected Dictionary<int, T> Years { get; set; } = new Dictionary<int, T>();
        
        public Statistics() { }

        public Statistics(Dictionary<int, T> years)
        {
            Years = years ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(years));
        }

        public T this[int year]
        {
            get
            {
                return Years.TryGetValue(year, out var value) ? value : new T();
            }
            set
            {
                Years[year] = value;
            }
        }

        public IEnumerator<(int Year, T Value)> GetEnumerator()
        {
            foreach (var element in Years)
            {
                yield return (element.Key, element.Value);
            }
    
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

I need somehow to be able to serialize/deserialize `Statistics<T>` class using `System.Text.Json`. This serialized object should look like serialized Dictionary in json.

Here is a sample code with comments of what I need

```
using System.Text.Json;
using SerializeCustomEnumerable;

JsonSerializerOptions jSerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions()
{
    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
    IncludeFields = true
                
};

//populate our statistics object
var firstPerson = new Person() { Age = 5 };
var secondPerson = new Person() { Age = 10 };
var dict = new Dictionary<int, Person>()
{
    [0] = firstPerson,
    [1] = secondPerson
};
var simplestat = new Statistics<Person>(dict);
  


//this is what the json should look like
string expectedJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(dict, jSerOptions);
//this is what I get
string serialized = JsonSerializer.Serialize(simplestat, jSerOptions);

//and also here deserialization fails... :(
var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Statistics<Person>>(serialized, jSerOptions);
```

But there is a catch to it. I can't use `Converters` in `JsonSerializerOptions`. (The reason is that this serialization is being done in different code base which is not managed by me. I know only that they call `JsonSerializer.Serialize(dict, jSerOptions);` )

Comment: You are messing a couple concepts together. Use a container collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest option would be to just implement `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`:

```
public class Statistics<T> : IEnumerable<(int Year, T Value)>, IDictionary<int, T> where T : new()
{
   // ...
}
```

And direct all the interface members calls to `Years`. If you want you can make `IDictionary` interface implementation to be [an explicit one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation).

The second option would be to implement a [custom converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0).

Also maybe useful - [Deserialize a class that implements IEnumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74622159/2501279) (though a bit different case)

Comment: Implementing `IDictionary<>` definitely works. VS even gives you a nice one-click fix `Implement interface through 'Years'`

Comment: In the end I used custom converter with `JsonConverterAttribute`, because our datastructure is more complex, than in this simple example.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I wrote a custom converter and we are using it together with `JsonConverterAttribute`. This converter works for all of our objects if we remove `CanConvert` override.

```cs
public class StatisticsPerYearConverter : JsonConverter<object>
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert)
    {
        // Check if the type is a Statistics<> instance
        // but we do not even need this CanConvert method since Read and Write are more universal
        return 
            (
                typeToConvert.IsGenericType &&
                typeToConvert.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(StatisticsPerYear<>))
            ||
            (
                typeToConvert.BaseType?.IsGenericType == true &&
                typeToConvert.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(StatisticsPerYear<>)
            );
    }

    public override object Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.StartObject)
        {
            throw new JsonException();
        }

        // Create an instance of the target type
        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeToConvert);

        // Read the JSON object
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.EndObject)
            {
                return instance;
            }

            if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.PropertyName)
            {
                var propertyName = reader.GetString();
                var property = typeToConvert.GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

                // Skip the property if it's not found or if it's an indexer
                if (property == null || property.GetSetMethod(true) is null)
                {
                    reader.Skip();
                    continue;
                }

                reader.Read();

                var propertyValue = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(ref reader, property.PropertyType, options);
                property.SetValue(instance, propertyValue);
            }
        }
        
        throw new JsonException("JSON does not match the expected format.");

    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var valueType = value.GetType();
        
        // read publicProperties
        var publicProperties =
            valueType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
                .Where(p => p.CustomAttributes.All(a => a.AttributeType != typeof(JsonIgnoreAttribute)));
        // read privateProperties
        var privateProperties =
            valueType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                .Where(p => p.CustomAttributes.Any(a => a.AttributeType == typeof(JsonIncludeAttribute)));

        var allProps = publicProperties.Union(privateProperties)
            .Where(prop => prop.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0); // remove underlying indexer field
        
        writer.WriteStartObject();

        foreach (var property in allProps)
        {
            var val = property.GetValue(value);
            writer.WritePropertyName(property.Name);
            JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, val, options);
        }
            
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
}
```